# Java 1.8 time functionality

Tags: java, time, java-8, java-time

So Java 1.8 comes with a whole new (and old) bunch of classes to manage time calculations: `java.time.Instant`, `java.time.LocalTime`, `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`, and maybe more...

But why is there no simple way to calculate the time difference between any of these? I would expect "time_later - time_earlier" to be the most used manipulation of time, but this is nowhere to be seen. I cannot subtract one LocalTime from the other and get a new LocalTime; I cannot subtract one Instant from the other to get a new Instant. Instead I have to fiddle with ChronoUnits.between, and long milliseconds and whatnots to achieve this very useful thing.

Why is this? There has to be something going on that I do not get? Or I'm just daft...?

Comment: Because Java only defines operators for primitives. The main point is that getting the difference between two times is **not simple**. What about leap years/seconds? Different time zones? Daylight savings? Local time discontinuities?

Comment: So.. because it is not simple it is not available. Is that it? I would have thought exactly the opposite... Because it is not simple it should be implemented correctly once and for all.

Comment: No, it is not available because there is no clear idea of what `time1 - time2` should do! See above.

Comment: Calculating the difference between two dates/time is actually very complicated, when you include such things as leap years, millinium and century boundaries, this is why we have the a Duration class. Take a look at [Date and Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) for more details.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you say. That it is complicated I agree with, but... when I am flying across time zones and different DST's, my itinerary can give me the amount of time I spend on the airplane, and to me this would seem to be the difference between landing time and take off time. Thus, this difference seems clear and possible to calculate. Is it then a matter of exactness?

Comment: When flying  the duration is usually based on an observable amount of time from the perspective of the flyer. That doesn't mean a 10 hour flight will out you back or forward 10 hours

Comment: @OppfinnarJocke Please update the title of your question to match specifically it's content.

Answer (score 4):

Before Java 8, the usual answer to your question was "use Joda Time"

- http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html

But the author of Joda Time (Stephen Colebourne) was deeply involved in the new Java 8 time classes and methods.  Here are two very good articles:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

For your specific question, you might want to consider Java 8 "Duration" and "LocalTime", "LocalDate" and/or "LocalTimeDate" (among other options):

```
// A duration of 3 seconds and 5 nanoseconds
Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(3, 5);
Duration oneDay = Duration.between(today, yesterday);

// Tomorrow
LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);

// Yesterday
LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().plusDays(-1);

// before 5 houres and 30 minutes
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusHours(5).minusMinutes(30);
```

Comment: I think the OP is aware of classes like Period or Duration etc., but he wants something impossible - see my answer.

Comment: FYI, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) has some advantages over java.time. Both Joda-Time and java.time have their pros and cons. Fortunately we can use both if we are careful with the `import` statements. Also, there is a [project adding more features to java.time](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra).

Answer (score 3):

Citation:

"I cannot subtract one LocalTime from the other and get a new LocalTime"

The main reason why this is a fundamentally wrong idea is a physical and mathematical one. Objects like `LocalTime` or `Instant` etc. represent a point in time on a time axis. But the difference between two points in time can only be a duration, that is a length in time. Mathematically you have the result in another dimension (point versus line). **So the subtraction of two points in time cannot yield another point in time.**

But measuring the distance between two points in time in terms of units makes sense, and this operation is supported by JSR-310 (aka java.time-package) as you have correctly seen. By the way, the duration/period-calculations are somehow limited (i.e. no mixed years, days, hours -between-operation like in Joda-Time), but in general between-methods like in class `ChronoUnit` are not something complex "to fiddle around". It is simple and easily understandable.

Comment: Yes, I realized this morning that this is the obvious answer. Instant, LocalTime, etc represent points in time, while subtracting them generates a time interval, which is of course not representable as a point in time. My bad... Thanks

Comment: @OppfinnarJocke Well, I suspect some people have used `Date` as replacement for a duration type because JDK had not offered such one. Of course, this has always been a dangerous work-around or rather dirty hack because sometimes people have also forgotten to set the timezone to UTC and then were not even aware of strange timezone side effects...

Answer (score 1):

Methods are provided to calculate the difference between two points in time.

```
Instant a = Instant.now().minusSeconds(2);
Instant b = Instant.now().plusSeconds(2);

Duration difference = Duration.between(a, b);

long secsBetween1 = a.until(b, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
long secsBetween2 = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(a, b);
```

`Duration` is the main object for representing an amount of time, and `Duration.between` is the a key method for creating it.

`ChronoUnit.between` and `Temporal.until` are the slightly lower-level methods that return the difference as a `long` for a specific unit.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the functionality you want by using `java.time.Instant.toEpochMilli()`.  This gets you the same functionality as the old `java.util.Date.getTime()`.

As long as you don't have to deal with time zones, `Instant` is pretty much all you'll need.  Don't get confused by all the rest of the stuff.

If you do have to deal with time zones, a lot of the complexity becomes necessary, though there's some extra complexity in the package due to overgenerality.

Comment: If you don't have to deal with timezones, LocalXxx is more appropriate than Instant which brings you back to the inferno of the legacy date api...

Comment: @assylias Actually the legacy Date API works fine if you don't have to deal with time zones.  It's only when you need to start expressing things in different time zones that it becomes a problem.  In contrast, using LocalXxx classes can get you into all sorts of trouble if you're not careful; for example, they can't be used as timestamps because they don't identify a single point in time, but rather different points in time in different time zones.